# What is the cheapest way, by public transport, of getting from Tournai to Lille airport?

Tags: public-transport, lille

I need to get from Brussels to Lille airport. I can easily and cheaply get to Tournai by train.

From Tournai I will need to get to the airport, but I would like to spend the day in Lille.

What are the cheapest options for that?

I found there is train connection and a shuttle to the airport, but I was trying to find other options as I have enough time.

Comment: Does your cheap train allow you to go to Mouscron instead of Tournai? From Mouscron you are very close to the final stop CH Dron of the Lille metro https://www.transpole.fr/fr/metro_tram/lignes-metro.aspx. It is about 4km from Mouscron station to CH Dron which you could walk. There also is a bus connecting both.

Comment: @ptityeti might be possible yes. I assumed tournai would be the closest since that's where the belgium rail system tells me I should pick another train.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the direct slow train from Brussels to Courtrai / Kortrijk, then train from there to Lille (cheap ["trampoline"](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/abroad/lille/trampoline-1-day.aspx) tickets available for the [cross-border hop](http://www.eurometropolis.eu/life-in-the-eurometropolis/getting-around/takingthetrain.html), if you can't get a cheap through ticket), then bus to the airport when you're done seeing the city

Comment: @Gagravarr Trampline allows unlimited travel. A single ticket from the last Belgian station to Lille will be cheaper if you want just one way.

Comment: What does the trampline allow? Also bus? Would the shuttle to the airport be included?

Answer (score 4):

From Tournai to Lille, you can use the train. It takes 30 minutes and costs less than 10 €.

Lille airport isn't far from Lille downtown. There is a shuttle from Lille railway station to the Lille Lesquin airport. It takes about 20 minutes and costs 8 €.

I believe those are the cheapest options and it still allows you to visit the city as Lille Grand Place is just 10-15 minutes walking distance from the railway stations.

Comment: Kortrijk-Lille and Tournai-Lille should only be [€8 for the special Trampoline cross-border ticket](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/abroad/lille/trampoline-1-day.aspx), more details [on the Euro-region website](http://www.eurometropolis.eu/life-in-the-eurometropolis/getting-around/takingthetrain.html)